# Numbers: Creating a Summary table based on values from different table

Tags: numbers

I have a table that looks much like this:

[image]

That **Category** column is entered manually and will have several duplicated values.

I’d LOVE to be able to create a “Summary” table that manages to copy and manipulate some of this data. Namely:

- It would take the “Category” columns with its duplicates, remove duplicated and sort the list;
- Have a second column that sums all values in that category’s fields;
- And finally, have a third row that shows how many times the original keywords appeared in the first table.

Here is a screenshot of what I’m trying to achieve:

[image]

Possible??

Comment: As of Numbers 11.2, you can accomplish this using a [Pivot Table](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/intro-to-pivot-tables-tan7ce76e776/11.2/mac/1.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your *category* column contains categories that are correctly spelled each time, then a simple solution would be to use the `SUMIFS()` and the `COUNTIFS()` formulas.

- In the **Summary** table, add a *category* from the category column from the **Finances** table.
- Next, in the *Amount* column of your **Summary** table, add the following formula: `SUMIFS(2017 Finances::Amount,2017 Finances::Category,A2)` Where `A2` contains a unique category.
- In the *Count* column, use this formula: `COUNTIFS(2017 Finances::Category,A2)`
- Drag the formulas down the columns to fill for each category.
- Sort Ascending or Descending as desired.

The `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` compare the category column with the entry in the **Summary** table's entry.  If there is a match, it sums or counts based on the category.  Repeat as needed.

**NOTE:**

Dynamically creating a Summary table without knowing the categories is quite a bit more complicated as **Numbers** does not have [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) (as Excel or Google Sheets has) functionality as of the date this answer was posted.  Great suggestion for [Apple Feedback.](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

See the illustrations below.

---

[image: SUMIFS formula]

[image: Countifs formula]

Comment: What is like Access but for mac?

Comment: @Lisa FileMaker. $$$ but is a proper relational database unlike Numbers or Excel. OpenOffice had a database too IIRC.

Comment: This is really fabulous and so minimal. Everything else I found and/or tried was several combinations of functions. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works for you. Spreadsheets are great but they have their limits over a full blown database. But a database is overkill for this job. Vote up if you really want to thank me.  ;)